# Externalize the table name to yml | Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, yaml

I am trying to get the table name from yaml file for easy changing of table names in Spring Boot project (JPA).

I tried with `@Table(name="${table.name}")` but it didn't work.

Can anyone please help me with the sample code and yaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Table` annotation is processed by Hibernate and it doesn't provide a way to plug in custom processing of an annotation's attributes. This makes it too difficult for Spring Boot to allow you to use application properties in the attributes of `@Table` and any other Hibernate-processed annotation. If you're interested in learning more, [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/829) contains some more discussion about the problem and Hibernate's limitations.